# How get next element after "this" - pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have code:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-lightbox]');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

  links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imgLink = this.getAttribute('href');
    var imgTitle = this.getAttribute('title');
    var dataLightbox= this.getAttribute('data-lightbox');
    console.log(); //next element after "this." something like "links[i+1]" or i don't know...
  }, false);
}
```

I want to get 'data-lightbox' attribute for next element which I clicked currently. How to do it?

Comment: Did you try your own suggestion of `links[i+1]`?

Comment: @Santi That wouldn't work because `i` is modified immediately.

Comment: `links[i+1]` would actually work if you [fix the scope of `i`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572) for the closure

Comment: Why you need next element in eventListener?

Comment: Are all those links next to each other in the DOM? Then `this.nextSiblingElement` might do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a IIFE can do the trick to preserve the `i` scope

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-lightbox]');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
       links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var imgLink = this.getAttribute('href');
        var imgTitle = this.getAttribute('title');
        var dataLightbox= this.getAttribute('data-lightbox');
        console.log(links[i + 1]);
      }, false);
    })(i)

    }
```

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thanks for quick answer. :)
Also i try other solutions from here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the next element in the way you thought: `links[i + 1]`, although the `i` is an unique hoisted variable by this loop. You can, however, re-generate this `i` in the loop body, using variable declaration of `let` (only supported in ES6+) or using a new function scope inside that loop.

`let` acts like we were in a new scope, but not. It won't affect the previous `i` in this example, it'll only replace its presence at the block statement.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-lightbox]');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

  let i = i;

  links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imgLink = this.getAttribute('href');
    var imgTitle = this.getAttribute('title');
    var dataLightbox= this.getAttribute('data-lightbox');
    console.log(links[i + 1]);
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: I think it is important to add a note about browser support for `let` .. ES6

Comment: @LGSon Yeah, added

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue.

You can use bind (which would fix the scope issue) for the onclick event binding,while this you can send i to the method and you can  access the next element using i+1

check the following snippet

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-lightbox]');


  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

    links[i].addEventListener('click', onclick.bind(links[i], i));
  }

  function onclick(i) {

    var imgLink = this.getAttribute('href');
    var imgTitle = this.getAttribute('title');
    var dataLightbox = this.getAttribute('data-lightbox');
    if(links[i+1]!=undefined){
    var nextLightbox = links[i + 1].getAttribute('data-lightbox');
      }

    console.log(imgLink);
    console.log(dataLightbox);
    console.log(nextLightbox);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-lightbox=10>link1</a>
<a href="#" data-lightbox=20>link2</a><a href="#" data-lightbox=30>link3</a><a href="#" data-lightbox=40>link4</a><a href="#" data-lightbox=50>link5</a>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have mentioned, another way to go about this is using `nextSibling` on `this`.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-lightbox]');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

  links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imgLink = this.getAttribute('href');
    var imgTitle = this.getAttribute('title');
    var dataLightbox= this.getAttribute('data-lightbox');
    console.log(this.nextElementSibling);
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: Make that `nextElementSibling` so you don't catch a text node

Comment: Oh, yes. Will do.